# IMAP Port 143 Not Functioning When Using Hostname?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, imap, telnet

I am setting up a Mail Server on Azure (Windows Virtual Machine) using HMail and its all working great apart from not being able to connect my Outlook on my home PC.

I believe the issue is that when I telnet using the hostname, the connection fails.

```
telnet typhoeus-mail-1.cloudapp.net 143
```

However trying telnet using the localhost works and the webmail on the server works too.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 143
```

I have tried disabling Windows Firewall but this doesn't change the behaviour, how can I get this to work using my hostname? It does allow me to connect on port 25 using this.

```
telnet typhoeus-mail-1.cloudapp.net 25
```

using the Microsoft website testconnectivity.microsoft.com I get this message

```
Testing TCP port 143 on host typhoeus-mail-1.cloudapp.net to ensure it's listening and open: The specified port is either blocked, not listening, or not producing the expected response.
```

Does anybody know how I can make IMAP port 143 work from outside the server - To me it sounds like a firewall issue, but even with the firewall disabled it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Iain mentioned, 127.0.0.1 (loopback) is special and is not the same as your public endpoint for the host.  Since you're using Azure IaaS, make sure that TCP 143, and any other ports you may need, are opened as an endpoint for that VM.  Only RDP and remote PowerShell are opened by default, I believe.

Comment: Thanks BHall, I was missing the endpoint on the Azure Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The host name `typhoeus-mail-1.cloudapp.net` resolves to IP address `23.101.73.198`. This is not the same as `127.0.0.1`.

It would appear that HMail is not configured to listen on the `typhoeus-mail-1.cloudapp.net` IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TCP/IP address,that is currently set in hMailserver.
To allow for queries from any IP address,set the IP TCP/IP address to 0.0.0.0

Comment: The TCP/IP Addresses set in HMail are 0.0.0.0 and the IP Ranges incluces "Internet" from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Comment: Whats the priority assigned assigned?
LowerIP  0.0.0.0  UpperIP: 255.255.255.255
Have you allowed IMAP connections,by checking against IMAP?
What's have you assigned as your external IP,whats the priority assigned to this entry?

Comment: The priority for the Internet was 10 (which was the lowest). I have just found the issue to this problem though, Needed to add an Endpoint in the Azure Dashboard :P. Appreciate the help Peter thanks